# Navbar opens and collapse suddenly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0" />

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>

    <div class = "container">
    <div class="navbar" >


      <div class ="navbar-header">
        <!-- Place your logo here -->

        <div class="navbar-brand" >

            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"  alt="logo text"></a>

        </div>
    </div>


            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle  navbar-right " data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">

              <span class="icon-bar"><hr><hr><hr></span>

              <span class="icon-bar"></span>

              <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>

            <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse nav-collapse ">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <!--  Add require site page navigation -->                    

                    <li><a href="index.html" class="first active" style="color:#000000"> <i class="icon-globe"></i>HOME</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">

                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#000000"><i class="icon-user"></i>About Us<b class="caret"></b></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                          <li><a href="company.html" style="color:#000000">The Company</a></li>

                          <li><a href="vision.html" style="color:#000000">Vision</a></li>

                      </ul>

                  </li>

                      <li class="dropdown">

                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#000000"><i class="icon-user" style="color:#000000"></i>Team<b class="caret"></b></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                          <li><a href="team.html" style="color:#000000">Meet Our Team</a></li>

                          <li><a href="sister.html"style="color:#000000">Our Sister concerns</a></li>

                        </ul>

                      </li>

                    <li><a href="project.html" style="color:#000000"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>Projects</a></li>
```

Refer
                            
                            Contact Us

Web

Locate

```
                </ul>


            </div>


    </div>     
    </div>
```

check the problem at www.alaknandainfra.com/refer.php   the nav bar collapses suddenly in mobile view  . i spent many hours but can't find the mistake . and i want to align the toggle menu on the right side . when user click on toggle button the menu should come on the right side

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the height:0 at bootstrap-responsive.min.css:1240, that issue seems to be fixed.

```
.nav-collapse,.nav-collapse.collapse{
    /* height:0; */
    overflow:hidden
}
```